# Magnetic field and force

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Is the force on a wire zero if the direction of some net magnetic field is in the direction of the current. If not what would be the orientation of the wire such that the force is 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magnetic force on a charge moving parallel to the field.